# Creating an Online Shopping Cart

Tags: php

I am trying to sum the price of all products selected.
If I chose 2 Products for example, whose prices are 13 and 15
then the output will be : "13 15"

My question is, How can I output the result of the two items?
( for this example , 28 )

```
for ($pos=0; $pos<=$level2; $pos++) { 
    $level3 = $level1[$pos];
    echo " ";
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$level3'");
    $results2 = array();
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        $results2[] = $row2['price'];
        $level4 = array_sum($results2);
        echo "Price is".$level4;
    }
```

Comment: Do not use mysql_* in a new code it is depricated. Use PDO, mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$sum = 0;
for ($pos=0; $pos<=$level2; $pos++) { 
    $level3 = $level1[$pos];
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$level3'");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        $sum += $row2['price'];
    }
}
echo 'Price is '.$sum;
```

Comment: Hey there Anders! I did what you wrote and my output, according to my first example ( 2 items who's prices are 13 and 15) is : 

Price is 13Price is 15
How can I make the output like this:
Price is 28

Comment: Ah I see. I wasn't aware what the for loop was doing. `sum = 0;` should be before the for loop starts and `echo 'Price is '.$sum;` should be after the for loop closing } If I understand your code right